# How to persist instance of a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-persistence

Is there a way to persist instances of a class in memory or file system in Python? Can I do this with `shelve`?

The following line is part of [this tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#training-a-classifier) which takes a long time to execute, and I need to cache it for next program executions.

```
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_counts, training_data['targets'])
```

Type of `clf`:

```
>>> type(clf)
<class 'sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `shelve` to persist instances of a class. `shelve` gives you a dictionary interface, making the process relatively transparent.

Underneath, `shelve` uses the [`pickle` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html); if the `shelve` API doesn't fit your needs, you can go straight to that module.

`scikit-learn` explicitly support `pickle`, see [*Model persistence*](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html):

> After training a scikit-learn model, it is desirable to have a way to persist the model for future use without having to retrain. The following section gives you an example of how to persist a model with pickle.

Comment: Doesn't pickle have issues with some user defined objects?

Comment: @JakobBowyer: no, not really. Pickle may have issues with certain types of objects, but it is not specific to user defined objects.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks. I use `os.path.isfile` to check whether the dump file exist to load or not. Is this the right way? I use joblib which is mentioned in the link.

Comment: @hpn: you can use `os.path.isfile` or use exception handling (`try:`, `open(...)`, `except IOError: # handle file not being there`).